# How to include a C/C++ #defined directive into the Delphi external calling process

Tags: c++, delphi

I have a C/C++ VS compiled Dll and a Delphi library created from a C/C++ h-file. The h-file has macro defined directives. Included in all the C/C++ external and typedef calls have a directive DISPLAY_CALL included.

On conversion to Delphi, I excluded the DISPLAY_CALL directive as it did not fit with my Delphi conversion, The bulk of the DLL functions work perfectly except for certain functions and type calls where the DLL makes use of the DISPLAY_CALL directive to determine if it is a windows platform or not and will return an error if called in another platform (ignored within the DLL). However if the DISPLAY_CALL is excluded then an error is received on any platform so the DISPLAY_CALL directive needs to be received by the DLL. Compiling the C++ with Visual Studio confirms this error if excluding the DISPLAY_CALL directive.

I am using Tokyo 10.2.3 Enterprise.

I have searched on how to do this without any success.

So how do you include this DISPLAY_CALL directive into the Delphi external calling process. I have come accross dependency but I am unsure if this is the correct direction to take.

Below is an extract of both the C/C++ Code and then the current translated Delphi Code.

C/C++ code

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#define DISPLAY_CALL WINAPI
#else
#define DISPLAY_CALL
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

typedef void (DISPLAY_CALL *display_removed_cb)(int fd, void *user_data);

int DISPLAY_CALL display_get_device(display_device_handle *dev_handle);
```

Delphi code

```
const
DisplayName =  'display.dll';  //defined for windows stdcall

 type
  display_removed_cb = procedure(fd:integer; user_data:pointer);

function display_get_device (dev_handle:pdisplay_device_handle): integer; stdcall; external DisplayName name 'display_get_device';
```

I look forward to some superior knowledge on this.

Comment: First thing you need to learn is that there's no such language as "C/C++". You could have a DLL that's implemented using both the C and C++ languages, but even then please don't use the phrase "C/C++". And if you're only using *one* of the languages, use only that language in your question and the tags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I almost always share this sentiment but I have to make an exception here. This is a header file intended to be usable both with C and with C++ compilers, so is not written in C, not written in C++, but written in the common subset of the two. It's one of the few legitimate use cases for it.

Comment: The smoothest solution might be to instead use C++ Builder and then link it to whatever format that's convenient for Delphi? C++ Builder is basically Delphi playing dress-up, so it ought to be more suitable for this than VS.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Questions regarding the use of `extern "C"` in C++ programs is probably one of the few cases where both tags can be used together. I made an attempt to put together C and C++ tag usage guidelines [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360824/584518). It is a community wiki, feel free to edit or provide feedback!

Comment: @Lundin I doubt it. You'd still have to write the Delphi translations. C++ Builder can consume Delphi units, but not vice versa.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's too bad. But you should be able to have C++ Builder spit out a library that Delphi can link smoothly, perhaps with some tweaks to calling convention.

Comment: @Lundin Asker already has a library, compiled with MSVC in this case. Switching compiler won't make life any easier for the Delphi side. From the Delphi side it's just a black box. It doesn't matter which compiler was used to create the DLL. It's really not very hard to call DLLs from Delphi.

Comment: @Lundin: not viable. There are constructs in C++ and C that can't be directly translated to Delphi. But almost all constructs in Delphi can be translated to C++Builder's slightly modified (for Delphi) C++ . And Delphi won't link to .lib or .so files directly anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In effect, the C++ code is saying that `stdcall` is to be used on Windows, and the default calling convention (invariably `cdecl`) elsewhere.

Your question has a long spiel about what you think `DISPLAY_CALL` is used for that I'm afraid I cannot make any sense of. I think you are over thinking this and getting a little confused. It really is nothing more than a calling convention specification.

So, in your Delphi code, you should do something like this:

```
function display_get_device(dev_handle:pdisplay_device_handle): integer; 
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} stdcall; {$ELSE} cdecl; {$ENDIF}
  external DisplayName name 'display_get_device';
```

This assumes you wish to support platforms other than Windows. If not, and you only support Windows, then you can simply use `stdcall` unconditionally.

You must also specify the calling convention everywhere, and your Delphi code fails to do so. You missed it on the callback type. This should be:

```
type
  display_removed_cb = procedure(fd:integer; user_data:pointer); 
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} stdcall; {$ELSE} cdecl; {$ENDIF}
```

And obviously whenever you declare a function that will be passed as an `display_removed_cb` argument, you must also specify the appropriate calling convention.

Comment: Some more info: why `stdcall`? Because `WINAPI` is a macro itself, and that finally resolves to `__stdcall`. The default calling convention in C and C++, i.e. when nothing else is defined, is `cdecl`. You can find that info and more in my article [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).